# problema com um footer bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

Bom estou tentando fazer um footer, mas estou com um problema,   quando eu diminuo o zoom ela não fica no final da pagina como esssa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como está:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

html :

```
  <div class="container-fluid pt-4 pb-1 xd">
   <p class="text-left">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.xd{
    background-color:#000;
}
.xd p{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Gabriel tudo vai depender muito do seu projeto, mas basicamente vc precisa por `position:absolute` e `bottom:0` na sua `div`. Existem outras formas de fazer isso, mas vc tem que ver a que fica melhor pro seu projeto como falei...

Veja como fica no exemplo usando seu código e apenas ajustando o `position` e o `bottom`

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/400/300);
  background-size: cover;
}
.xd{
   background-color:#000;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
.xd p{
   color:#fff;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid pt-4 pb-1 xd">
  <p class="text-left">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </p>
</div>
```